# Salvar la conexion en el Setting de C#

Tags: c#

Buenas noches, gracias a todos de antemano, sigo pasando mi aplicacion de VB a C#, ya con ayuda de ustedes logre leer un archivo ini, cambiar en la cadena la base de datos a la que me quiero conectar, ahora llevo dias tratando de salvar la nueva cadena en la variable que tengo en el setting del proyecto de C#, espero su ayuda y les dejo el codigo de lo que necesito nuevamente.

En el proyecto en configuracion :

```
Nombre : mCnxSifco
Tipo   : Cadena de Conexion
Ambito : Aplicacion
Valor  : cadena a mi base de datos local
```

Cuando paso la nueva cadena de conexion quiero hacer un reemplazar o salvar en la variable mCnxSifco con la variable nueva que contiene la nueva conexion llamada aoCnxSifco, pero me envia error y no he podido guardar o reemplazar esta para mis conexiones futuras.

Nuevamente repito que en visual basic solo escribia esta intruccion

```
Me.Item("mCnxSifco") = acCnxApp.Trim.Replace("qmasuser", acUserId)
```

Espero su ayuda ya que llevo semanas peleando o trabajando en este codigo.

gracias

AM

Comment: tenes un archivo de configuracion o de recursos?

Comment: Si, asi es ese mismo es que el leo para crear la cadena de conexion es un archivo ini. Siguiendo un comentario a este hilo de otro colega, me indico que usara un programa o buscara de conversion y probando resolvi con uno donde me mando la instruccion :  cree una variable tipo var que es la aoCadena del valor anterior y luego hice esto donde me funciono al 100%, ahora estoy con otra conversion.   Gracias a todos seguire en este proceso de conversion que estoy trabajando y consultandoles        
  this["mCnxSifco"] = aoCadena;

Comment: Echa un ojo al fichero 'app.config', que viene a ser el equivalente del .ini en el entorno del visualstudio C#. Es un fichero de recursos de la aplicación, te aparece en el Explorador de Soluciones. Está en formato XML, con pares clave-valor.
Con ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] obtienes el valor de la clave indicada.
AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key) elimina la clave-valor.
AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value) introduce una clave-valor.